# Gephi finds no node/relation properties on import

Tags: neo4j, gephi, graphml, neo4j-apoc

I want to visualize my Neo4j dataset with Gephi. After installing [apoc](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index31.html) and get it working, I called `call apoc.export.graphml.all("/tmp/test2.graphml",{})` and I get the right file. Now I import/open this .graphml-file in Gephi 0.9.1 but in the import-window I can´t see any properties. Also in the graph itself there´re no properties on the nodes / relations. 
Does anyknow know, what I´m doing wrong or have I forgot to set the right configuration-parameters?

Thanks in advance

---

UDPATE

---

this is my procedure call:

```
call apoc.export.graphml.all("/tmp/test2.graphml",{}) yield nodes, relationships, properties, time
```

this is the snapchot from the Neo4j browser

[image: Result Neo4j browser]

I´ve loaded this file from my server and openend it in Gephi, resulted in this:

[image: Gephi view nodes]
[image: Gephi view edges]

Like you see, my properties are still not there...

Answer (score 0):

Apoc has a custom procedure, that exports data to Gephi in one single step. You will need to download a  [graph streaming plugin](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/graph-streaming/) for Gephi,so you will be able to easily export data from Neo4j to Gephi using `apoc.gephi` procedures. 
Example:

```
MATCH path = (:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(:Person)
CALL apoc.gephi.add(null,'workspace1',path,'weight') yield nodes
RETURN distinct("success")
```

Check out [the docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_streaming_data_to_gephi) and this [tutorial](https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/04/01/neo4j-to-gephi) for more info.

Comment: I´ve already had a look at this Plugin, but it doesn´t work with my Neo4j-Version (3.1.0)!
I´ve just updated my original post with the code and the snapshots...

Comment: Graph streaming plugin is for Gephi, not Neo4j. If you do not have the latest APOC, you can use `CALL apoc.gephi.add(null,'workspace1',path) yield nodes`, which works for me, but you are always exporting an unweighted network. If you want to also export weights to Gephi I suggest you upgrade to Neo4j 3.1.3 and latest APOC to date, which is https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/tag/3.1.3.6 right now.

Comment: I´ve tried your suggestion and updated Neo4j (to version 3.1.3) and apoc.  
now, when i call the abovementioned procedure I´ll get this error: 
`Failed to invoke procedure 'apoc.gephi.add': Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: NODE[380] has no property with propertyKey="name".`
My nodes got the properties "firstname" and "lastname".. is this the problem? How do i declare, that the firstname (or lastname) should be exported to GephI?

Comment: In current version i think it is still hardcoded. Check https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.1/src/main/java/apoc/gephi/Gephi.java .... easiest solution is to set the name property as first name + last name

Comment: ok, i added this property but now I get another error... :( is it generally possible to stream from a remote server to gephi?

Comment: Is you use graph streaming plugin for Gephi you can... and you have to start master server as shown in tutorial

Comment: ok.. I´ve done this like described in the tutorial and I get this error `Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.gephi.add`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url invalid URL as json: no protocol: 78.47.***.***/arbeitsbereich1/operation=updateGraph`
I´m so sorry for this, but I don´t find any description/working example for a stream to a remote server...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143209/discussion-between-andy-and-tomaz-bratanic).